# Is possible create a Real Time Multiplayer game web based?

Tags: google-play-services

I am trying to use the Google Play Game Services to create a multiplayer game based web, but I can't create the Rooms. Is possible use the Google play game services on web to use the real multiplayer?

```
<meta name="google-signin-clientid" content="32241234345-oklsdfhgiodf89789gfgfy9ym.apps.googleusercontent.com" />
    <meta name="google-signin-cookiepolicy" content="single_host_origin" />
    <meta name="google-signin-callback" content="signinCallback" />
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
    <!--meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games-->

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js"></script>
    <script>

    var appId = '0000000000';

    var clientId = '0000000000-dfdsfsdfsdfsdgsdgfsdtodnjj8hq6hjm.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    var apiKey = 'SDFGSDKjjk123123';
    //var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me';
    var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games';


function create(){

            gapi.client.request({
            path: 'https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/rooms/create',
            method: 'POST',
            callback: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            }
            });

            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on whether or not you want the game to be in real time or not. If you are ok with a turn based multiplayer game then you can use the REST API.

For more info visit this link: https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/turnbasedMultiplayer

If you want multiplayer to be real-time then the answer is No. You currently can not do that with Googles API. It is only available on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately only works with Android and iOS

> The Google Play Games real-time multiplayer service is supported on
>   these platforms:
>
> ```
> Android through the Google Play services SDK
> iOS through the iOS SDK
> ```

https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer